# Query to join on calculated amount

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've searched and tried different expressions but can not seem to get the results I'm looking for. I have two tables JuneRecon and USASRecon, I need to join these two tables on the amount field, however in one table the amount will be -3.00 and the other will be 3.00. I need to add these fields together to equal 0 and return only a few rows from each when they've been identified as being equal, hope that makes sense.

What I've tried:
Expression in query builder: Subtotal: Sum(CCur([JuneRecon!Amount]+[USASRecon!Amount]<0)) -gives following error message "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'System' as part of an aggregate function"

I'd like to return the results grouped by which rows equal 0 and those that don't I would like them be Null

Comment: Please show us some code you've tried and examples of data you need to return.

Answer (score 0):

It might look something like this:

```
select *
from 
  table1 
  inner join table2
    on table1.col + table2.col = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Query  with the two tables, you can even use Query Design

Make a new feild with an expression : IIf([JuneRecon]![amount]+ [USASREcon]![amount] =0, 1,0))
enter the crietria to just be 1 aka True

You could do the same thing with a SQL WHERE statement.